# UIStackView's labels with emoji characters are not rendered properly when filled proportionally and horizontal axis after device rotates

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have `UIStackView` with two `UIlabels` with **vertical** axis and **fill proportionally** distribution and alignment **center**. One of them contains emoji characters.

This is how it looks in portrait mode:

[image]

When device rotates, then I change axis to **horizontal**, and alignment to **first baseline**. This is how it looks after rotating:

[image]

When label doesn't contain emoji characters everything is fine:

[image]

Where is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the following method, which should be added to controller:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    view.layoutSubviews()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that one of the constraints on the label with the emoji is "height". If one of the constraints is already "height", try making the height of the larger.